Polars-Python: Compare list columns
In Python Polars, I have a dataframe like the below:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"sets": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [9, 10]], "optional_members": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [9, 0]]}
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬──────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members │
│ ---       ┆ ---              │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╡
│ [1, 4, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        │
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [1, 2]           │
└───────────┴──────────────────┘

I would like to build an expression that gets me the elements of the first column that are in the second, keeping the shape of the former, i.e:

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ result              │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                 │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]          │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ [1, 4, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, false, true] │
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, false]       │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────────┘


I have tried using eval over the first list, something like:

func = lambda x, y: y.list.contains(x)

df.with_columns(contains=
                pl.col("optional_members")
                .list.
                eval(func(pl.element(), pl.col("optional_members"))))


But the pl.col() expression cannot be in an eval.
How could we aaddress this while keeping the solution in a single expression?
Thanks to @roman comment, a point need to be made: the check should be done regardless of the position.

in your example same elements have the same position, but do you need to check it regardless of position? For example, if first column contains [1,2] and second column contains [2,1] do you want to have [true, true] or [false, false]?

This is an amazing point. Indeed, I do need to check regardless of the position. I will add it to the description of the issue.

There is .list.set_intersection() to actually get the intersection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79182194/ may be relevant depending on what you need to do next with the bools.

If you need to compare elements on the same position:
df.with_columns(
    (pl.col.sets.list.explode() == pl.col.optional_members.list.explode())
    .implode()
    .over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    .alias("result")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ result             │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]         │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, true, true] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, true]       │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ [9, 0]           ┆ [true, false]      │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────┘

If you need to compare elements regardless of position then it's a bit more complicated:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col.sets.explode().is_in(pl.col.optional_members.explode())
    .implode()
    .over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    .alias("result")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ result             │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]         │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, true, true] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, true]       │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ [9, 0]           ┆ [true, false]      │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────┘

If your lists are not very long or if all the lists are the same length, you can also try to use

pl.Expr.list.get().

m = df.select(pl.col.sets.list.len().max()).item()

df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.col.optional_members.list.contains(pl.col.sets.list.get(i, null_on_oob=True))
        for i in range(m)
    ).list.head(pl.col.sets.list.len())
    .alias("result")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ result             │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]         │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, true, true] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, true]       │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ [9, 0]           ┆ [true, false]      │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────┘


Based on some of the feedback, and taking into account the guideline on structs, I think I found an interim solution that works regardless of the dtype (and the order), although it involves map_elements:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"sets": [[2, 1, 3], [2, 3], [9, 10]], "optional_members": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [9, 0]]}
)

def test(m, n):
    return [element in n for element in m]


df.with_columns(contains=
                pl.struct(["sets", "optional_members"])
                .map_elements(lambda x: test(x["sets"], x["optional_members"])))

┌───────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ contains           │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]         │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [2, 1, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, true, true] │
│ [2, 3]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, false]      │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ [9, 0]           ┆ [true, false]      │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────┘


I'd advice to avoid running python functions and try to keep your solution within pure polars expressions, for performance reasons.

You are right! Your method is ~112x faster than using map_elements for a simple 1000 rows df and list of 600 elements.

If your lists have fixed length there's another possible solution btw

One possibility would be to explode, compare, then group_by.agg:
(df.with_row_index() # to be able to group back to original rows
   .explode(['sets', 'optional_members'])
   .with_columns(pl.col('sets').eq(pl.col('optional_members')).alias('result'))
   .group_by('index').agg(pl.col(['sets', 'optional_members', 'result']))
   .drop('index')
)

Another option could be to compute the difference of values and cast to booleans:
df.with_columns(pl.col('sets').sub(pl.col('optional_members'))
                  .cast(pl.List(pl.Boolean)).alias('result')
               )

This would invert the result, but you could tweak it using:
df.with_columns(pl.lit(1).sub(
                   pl.col('sets').sub(pl.col('optional_members'))
                     .cast(pl.List(pl.Boolean))
                   ).cast(pl.List(pl.Boolean)).alias('result')
               )

Output:
┌───────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ sets      ┆ optional_members ┆ result              │
│ ---       ┆ ---              ┆ ---                 │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64]        ┆ list[bool]          │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ [1, 4, 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]        ┆ [true, false, true] │
│ [1, 0]    ┆ [1, 2]           ┆ [true, false]       │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ [9, 0]           ┆ [true, false]       │
└───────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────────┘


Thanks! The challenge for me is to keep it at expression level, so I can run it in a single with_columns. It is part of a number of expressions that I want to run in parallel, and I am collecting them before accessing the dataframe. Do you think that is possible?

@yz_jc see update for another approach (assuming you have integers), I don't have a suggestion for strings.

I get a sub operation not supported for dtype `list[i64]`  ?

@Luuk this is a relatively recent addition, update your polars version

ok upgraded from 0.20.7 to 1.14.0, now it works!
